# open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ without torsion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, galois-representations

In [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.colmez/FamillesDeRham.pdf) of Laurent Berger & Pierre Colmez, I have a question in the proof of lemma3.1.1 on page7.

We have a exact sequence of group $1\rightarrow A\rightarrow \widetilde\Gamma_H \rightarrow B\rightarrow1$ where $A$ is a finite group and $B$ is an open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ without torsion, then why $B$ is topological isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a topological group? I know open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are all of $p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$, but what about $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

Let $C_H$ be the center of $\widetilde\Gamma_H$, why $C_H$ is of finite index in $\widetilde\Gamma_H$? Can we see $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a subgroup of $\widetilde\Gamma_H$?

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3484919/276986  $1+p^2\Bbb{Z}_p$ has finite index and is isomorphic with $\log$ to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $\Bbb{Z}_p^*/ (\Bbb{Z}_p^*)_{tors}$ is a $\Bbb{Z}_p$ module thus it is $\cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ and so are its finite index subgroup $H/H_{tors}$

Comment: @reuns   $\mathbb{Z}_p^*/{(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)}_{tors} $is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module, but why it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 If $A$ and $B$ are two groups and $A$ is a finite group, then for any element $b$ of infinite order in $B$, $(a,b)$ is a element of infinite order in $A\times B$ for any $a\in A$, so all elements of infinite order in $A\times B$ are contained in $A\times B_{tor-free}$, so I don't know why you said every torsion free subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ lies in $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a answer myself.

If $B$ is a open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\times (1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ without torsion, then $B\subset 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ since all elements of finite order in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are $p-1$-th roots of unity. But we also have $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and open subgroups in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $n\geq0$, so $B\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Note that this needs a little adjustment in the case $p=2$. The comment by user reuns is more general and includes that case as well.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg But I don't know why user reuns metioned $1+p^2\mathbb{Z}_p$, and he said that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*/{(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)}_{tors}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, is this because $\mathbb{Z}_p^*/{(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)}_{tors}\cong 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: It's exactly because in the case $p=2$, the multiplicative subgroup $1+p\mathbb Z_p$ is *not* torsion-free, and is *not* isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Z_p$. However, $1+p^2\mathbb Z_p$ is both of these things regardless of what $p$ is.